# SQL Server unable to insert rows if not sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert, system-administration

Insert/update a row in SQL Server 2012 without assigning sysadmin role to domain user. User has db_reader an db_writer membership in the database

Row inserts/updates normally

When domain user is not given sysadmin role there is no error but no row is inserted/updated

Comment: Show us the code being executed.  Also any relevant table definitions and any triggers on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

check this might help you to give access

db_datawriter
The db_datawriter role is like the db_datareader role in that it gives implicit access to tables and views within a database. It also can be blocked by an explicit DENY for the user or for a role the user is a member of. Unlike db_datareader, however, db_datawriter gives INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions . Again, since the permission is implicit, you will not see these rights show up in sys.database_permissions. And like with db_datareader, you'll have to check the membership of this role to determine actual permissions in the event of an audit.

The db_datawriter role gives implicit access to INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE against all tables and views in a database.
In SQL Server 2005 and up, an explicit DENY will block access to objects.
Typically developer are not members of this role in production unless all users are.
While less common than with db_datareader, it is not all that unusual to see this role used in production for normal users.
Applications will occasionally need this role.
Creating a user-defined database role and explicitly defining permissions is still preferred over the use of this role.

Comment: i understand db_reader and db_writer roles. The point is unless my domain users have sysadmin server role they are unable to add/update records into db. I do not want them to be sys_admin this is a security risk.